# Increase div height while button is pressed, then move up on release

Tags: css, reactjs

I have a piano keyboard rendered in React and I want to replicate a trailing note effect that's also present in Synthesia. That is, while a key is pressed, a trailing note should be rendered above the key, it's height continuously increasing while that key is pressed, and once released, the trailing note should move up at the same speed that its height was increasing.

I managed to apply the move-up part of the notes:

```
  componentDidMount(){
    setTimeout(this.applyMoveUp,1)
  }

  applyMoveUp =()=>{
    console.log("apply move up")
    this.ref.current.classList.toggle('trailingNote-moveUp')
  }
```

and this is the css:

```
.trailingNote {
  background:black;
  width:20px;
  transition: transform  5s;
  transition-timing-function: linear;
  }
 
.trailingNote-moveUp{
  transform: translateY(-700px);
}
```

This renders the trailing note on the screen and applies the trailingNote-moveUp css class to it so it starts moving up as soon as it's on the screen, but its height does not increase.

I tried using css keyframes as well (https://codepen.io/Sederfo/pen/NWyEjvK) but I'm not sure how to tell CSS to continue the first transformation until the key is released and how to code all of this in React since I am new to this framework.

How can this effect be achieved in React?

Comment: I don't exactly understand the problem, but does applying another transition to height work? `transition: transform 5s linear, height 5s linear;` and then in `moveUp` set height to something? As a sidenote, instead of applying the `moveUp` class you could use the `:active` pseudo-class. Something like https://jsbin.com/vodesixeve/1/edit?html,css,output

Comment: I don't know the height that the note would reach. Let's say the speed at which the height increases is 10px per second. If I keep the key pressed for 2 seconds, its final height would be 20px, then it would start moving up.

Comment: Updated my question with a codepen that roughly does what I need.

Comment: Ah, I see what you want to do. You'll probably have to manage the height via inline styles in javascript. Let me see if I can make an example.

Comment: Not the cleanest solution, but I think this is what you're looking for https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-waterfall-cqj2ik?file=/src/App.js

I think you'll ultimately want to dispose of these elements once they leave the screen and the hardcoded 700px could be troublesome.

Comment: Yes! This is exactly what I was looking for! Please post it as an answer so I can mark it. Thank you!